# How to import javax.faces library in Eclipse using JDK8?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, import, java-8, java

Based on the [advice to use JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466451/could-current-approach-to-tdd-in-servlets-be-optimized), the [following sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjaam.html) would like to be run in order to learn more about JSF and to implement this technique into the servlet. However, a number of libraries is unable to be imported:

```
package tobedefinedservlet;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Hello {

    final String world = "Hello World!";

    public String getworld() {
        return world;
    }
}
```

*javax.faces*

`The import javax.faces cannot be resolved`

*ManagedBean*

`ManagedBean cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: And you are sure you included a JSF library like for example Mojarra in the classpath of your application?

Comment: I have checked the java build path again and the incorrect jar was imported. The errors are gone now. Thank you.

Comment: @QueryLars You should add that as the answer.

Comment: This link would help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46019133/4783846

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include a JSF library like for example Mojarra in the classpath of your application.

First of all have a look at the Primefaces [user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) (especially chapter 2.2). You can download e.g. Mojarra [here](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/2.2/download.html) and include the JAR or add the [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api) to your POM.xml if you are using Maven. Hope that helps.

Comment: First of all have a look at the [Primefaces user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) (especially chapter 2.2). You can download e.g. Mojarra [here](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/2.2/download.html) and include the JAR or add the dependency to your `POM.xml` if you are using Maven. Hope that helps. It is not quite clear what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) for build automation, add the latest [jsf-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api) dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or the latest [javax.faces-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-api) [implementation](https://javaee.github.io/javaserverfaces-spec/):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

However, note that JSF is [integrated](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/JSF_Guide/en-US/html/jsf.deployer.config.html) into most Java EE application servers, such as JBoss.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471468/do-i-need-jsf-api-or-jsf-impl-or-both-to-start-using-jsf-why-are-they-not-merge).

Answer (score 1):

in my case ...I went to project properties and in the search engine I wrote facets ... I went to the right of the window and selected the runtime tab and select wildfly ... then apply and apply and close and solve ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using maven you have to manually install the jar. You can download it at this link:

[javax.faces](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1)

If you're using eclipse you can right click your Web App project and click properties at the bottom. Then under the java build path make sure the libraries panel at the top is selected then select the Web App library and on the right click Add External JARS. You can go to your downloads folder and select the jsf-api-2.1.jar and refresh the project and you can now import that annotation.