# Do I need jsf-api or jsf-impl or both to start using JSF? Why are they not merged?

Tags: jsf, jar

I have started studying JSF and I would like to know what is the JAR to include within our classpath to start using JSF. Is it `jsf-api` or `jsf-impl`? Or we have to include both? And if it is both then why they are not merged?

Comment: Application servers ship the JSF implementation. If you happened to use one, you would not need to include additional unless the default version is not what you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll assume that you're not using a real Java EE application server like [WildFly](https://wildfly.org), [TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org), [Payara](https://payara.fish), etc, but a barebones JSP/Servlet container like [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org) which indeed doesn't ship with JSF out the box and you thus had to manually install it. Otherwise, all this fuss with JARs is unnecessary.

---

> *Is it jsf-api or jsf-impl? Or we have to include both?*

You need both. The `jsf-api.jar` contains the API, which exist of almost only abstract classes and interfaces. It are the `javax.faces.*` types which you are importing and using in your code. The `jsf-impl.jar` contains the implementation, which exist of the real hard working code. The implementation is internally loaded via factories in API. It are the `com.sun.faces.*` classes which you are **not** supposed to import and use directly in your code. If you do, then you wouldn't be able to switch to a different JSF implementation, such as MyFaces.

---

> *And if it is both then why they are not merged?*

There exist a merged JAR, the `javax.faces.jar`. You can pick this one instead of the two loose JARs.

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)
- [JSF implementations and component libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries)
- [Difference between Mojarra and MyFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530746/difference-between-mojarra-and-myfaces)
- [In simplest terms, what is a factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550612/in-simplest-terms-what-is-a-factory)
- [How to properly install and configure JSF libraries via Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081234/how-to-properly-install-and-configure-jsf-libraries-via-maven)

Comment: I found out think dependency
    <dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

Name of this  jar is different but It says 
This is the master POM file for Oracle's Implementation of the JSF 2.2 Specification.