# Unable to start the Tomcat server. Compiled using Java 1.7. Using JSF 2.0. Gives UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/faces/config/FacesInitializer

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, version, startup

I have java web application which was working earlier. I upgraded it to JDK 8, and compiled the code with JDK 1.7 compliance setting. I am however getting the below error when I start the server. I actually removed all references to JDK 8 and using JDK 7, still I get the below error.

```
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;.
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:06 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:eEducation' did not find a matching property.
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:06 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 997 ms
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eEducation]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eEducation]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/faces/config/FacesInitializer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1265)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 02, 2016 10:36:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I have checked all my build paths and JRE

I have checked that the jsf-impl.jar is complied with Major 49 version (Java 1.5). But the error which I am getting is from a class in this jar

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/faces/config/FacesInitializer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class com.sun.faces.config.FacesInitializer)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2948)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
```

I have tried all permutation and combination but it still doesn't work. 
Attached are the screenshots of my project's JDK settings.

here are the images of my settings

Compiler Settings

[Compiler Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQOK1.jpg)

[Java Build Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVS0y.jpg)

I can assure you that my Tomcat 7.0 is also running on JRE 1.7
(Unfortunately I cannot post more than 2 links)

Comment: Yes Balus C. It is not JSF 1.0. My bad. Here are the classfiles in the /WEB-INF/lib folder. But note it works if I replace the JDK with the version 1.8.

Comment: antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance.jar
charts4j-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
docx4j-2.8.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dsn.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-tools.jar
hibernate3.jar
imap.jar
itext-xtra-5.1.1.jar
itextpdf-5.1.1.jar
javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar
javax.faces-2.3.0-m04.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jta-1.1.jar
junit-4.3.1.jar
jxl.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mailapi.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar

Comment: poi-3.8-20120326.jar
poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar
pop3.jar
primefaces-3.4.1.jar
serializer.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
smtp.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-build-src-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar

Comment: spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-support-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-expression-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-framework-bom-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jms-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jms-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: spring-messaging-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-messaging-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-messaging-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-oxm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-test-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-test-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.0.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.0.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-websocket-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
tomahawk-1.1.11.jar
xml-apis.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Comment: These are all the files

Comment: Next time just edit the question (and keep out Spring JAR clutter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your list of JARs,

> - javax.faces-2.3.0-m04.jar
> - jsf-api.jar
> - jsf-impl.jar

Provided that jsf-impl.jar is compiled with Java 1.5, then this indicates that it's JSF 2.0. You're thus basically mixing JSF 2.3 (beta) and JSF 2.0 in one and same webapp. This makes no sense. JSF 2.3 is compiled with Java 1.8 and JSF 2.0 is compiled with Java 1.5. As per your exception, the JSF 2.3 classes got precedence in classloading and are actually being used.

Get rid of the JSF 2.3 JAR file.

If you still continue running after "fixing" the Java version, you'd sooner or later face one of following problems caused by mixing multiple different versioned JSF libraries:

- [java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897900/java-lang-illegalstateexceptioncould-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces-ap/)
- [java.lang.IllegalStateException : Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369903/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces/)
- [@ViewScoped calls @PostConstruct on every postback request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541813/viewscoped-calls-postconstruct-on-every-request)
- [Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)

Just do not mix multiple JSF libraries.

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page - Installation instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)
- [Do I need jsf-api or jsf-impl or both to start using JSF? Why are they not merged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471468/do-i-need-jsf-api-or-jsf-impl-or-both-to-start-using-jsf-why-are-they-not-merge/)

Comment: By Jove, @BalusC you are a genius. Bingo. It solved it. I never could have imagined that I added 2 of the JSF implementation. I had been on this for a week now and you just did it no time. I am thankful and humbled. I cannot upvote this as I have to earn 15 reputations. The stackobverflow would not take it unfortunately.