# When downloading Mojarra libraries for JSF it is showing error "zip file is empty" in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I'm working on JSF project, I'm trying to set up project facets in Eclipse, When I'm downloading Mojarra libraries for JSF2.2 it is giving error message. I'm using Eclipse Neon 2.

See the below image for more information.

[image: Mojarra libraries]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: I guess that's not a widely used feature. Why not just go with maven?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker It is old project, it will not support maven. Somehow I have added manually javax.faces.jar file to classpath. Now it's working fine

Answer (score 28, accepted):

***Update: Updated.***

**Adding Mojarra Manually When Eclipse Luna/NEON/Oxygen JSF Download Library Is Empty...**

When I was setting up a fresh install of JavaEE on my laptop today, the JSF Download Library would not return any results to download. Some searching suggested that I had to change my proxy settings but since I was not behind a proxy,

Actually some sorts are saying temporarily / Website is offline that's why its not downloadable ...

[image: If this problem is happening try out this]

it would not help me. Lucky enough, JSF are just another bunch of jars that can be added to a user library.

You can download the JSF Scroll down here for newest versions of JSF jars...

Download JSF API JAR  [JSF API jar file](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.2.20/jsf-api-2.2.20.jar)

Download JSF IMPL JAR  [JSF IMPl jar file](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.2.20/jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar)

Then simply;  click the **“Manage Libraries”** icon on the JSF capabilities page  **click “New”** and *name your library*

**click** “Add external jars” and browse to the jars you downloaded

[image: Name your libraries that you can take back your jars files]

[image: When jars are added then use your jsf as it is...]

Finally you are fully featured to the JSF Mojjara Library

Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for this descriptive  answer i was wondering why it is not working how ever the video is showing well now i am understood.

Comment: 2021 and the links are now dead!!

Comment: @Abdullah Khan I have updated links hope now you can download the jars. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

I have downloaded javax.faces.jar file from maven repository. Added that jar file to classpath, now it is working fine.

[javax.faces.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1)

Answer (score -4):

I found other sotution, when you start a new dynamic Web proyect pick "New runtime", then Oracle>Glassfish, install it and restart eclipse, JSF library is probided by Glassfish so in JSF Capabilities panel (when the new proyect is created) , glassfish is assigned by default (the System library). it works for me :)

Comment: That is like using an F-16 to kill a mosquito