# When downloading Mojarra libraries for JSF it is showing error “zip file is empty” in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I'm starting with JSF. 
  I'm doing a simple CRUD tutorial, using JSF, Bootstrap and MySQL.
  Dinamic Project Web module version 3.1.
  With JavaServer Faces 2.2 and Tomcat v8.5 Server.
  Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a
  Java SE Development 64 bit (Version 8, compilation 1.8.0)

I have the same problem raised here:
[When downloading Mojarra libraries for JSF it is showing error "zip file is empty" in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858251/when-downloading-mojarra-libraries-for-jsf-it-is-showing-error-zip-file-is-empt)

answer:
 Download  JSF API jar file
 Download JSF IMPl jar file

I see the answer you give here.
 But I have a doubt.
 Which of the files should be downloaded?
 The answer link gives a fairly long list of files. Which one of them do I download?
 How to know the file that I need to download for my project?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please add a direct link to the question you referred to by editing you question.

Comment: You can also donwload https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.18 which contains both: API + IMPL. Also read [JSF Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) for additional info on what you need and tutorlials.

Comment: But if you are starting new, start with JSF 2.3

Comment: Thanks so much Selaron.

Your help solved my problem. Again thank you very much.
I do not know where to mark to give as a very correct answer.
This page is not intuitive.      I am sorry my english.     Thanks a lot.